# switch (true) as alternative to else if

Tags: javascript

I've seen multiple times usage of `switch(true)` and have used it today myself instead of multiple `else ifs`. Here is the case I used it for:

```
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') != -1;
var isSafari = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') != -1;
var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') != -1;
var browser = null;
switch (true) {
    case isChrome:
        {
            browser = "chrome";
            break;
        }
    case isSafari:
        {
            browser = "safari";
            break;
        }
    case isFirefox:
        {
            browser = "firefox";
            break;
        }
}
```

My view is that much more explicit than multiple `else ifs`. Do you think it's a good approach?

Comment: Consider asking at [codereview.se] - this sort of question is of topic here on Stack Overflow. Happy coding.

Comment: Seems fine, but you don't need the curlybraces in the switch.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GjPUH/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really just a matter of personal opinion. `switch(true)` may be confusing at first, but it really doesn't matter with regards to speed or semantics. I, personally think that `if...else` looks better in this case, since there are so few options. If there were 10-15 browsers, I might use a `switch`.

If you're looking for pure conciseness, @adeneo's regular expression would work, but that would be even harder to understand, with this code

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
browser = ua.match(/(chrome|safari|firefox)/).length ? ua.match(/(chrome|safari|firefox)/)[0] : 'nope';

console.log(browser);
```

which looks really cool and concise, but seems a bit unintuitive. I'd just say that whatever you want to do is fine, there's no standard for things like this.

Comment: I'll upvote that, cool code! I agree that it might not be that readable for others, but for me it's actually more readable, as I hate scrolling through comments and long switches to figure out what is going on, and usually find it easier to read short concise statements instead, but that's just me, the switch or a condition is fine as well.